# jqgrid error when deleting row

Tags: javascript

I do some testing on jquery jqgrid but has problems :

```
jQuery("#navgrid").jqGrid(
        "navGrid",
        "#pagernav", 
        {}, //options 
        {}, // edit options 
        {}, // add options 
        {
            afterSubmit : function(response, postdata)
            {
                if(response.responseText == 'success')
                {
                    console.log(postdata);
                    alert('success and data should be changed')
                    console.log(postdata.id);
                    jQuery("#navgrid").delRowData(postdata.id);
                }
                else
                {
                    alert('failed and data should not be changed');
                }
                return true;
            },
            reloadAfterSubmit: true
        }, // del options 
        {} // search options 
);
```

I do two console.log on firebug for:

```
postdata => Object { oper="del", id="29"}
postdata.id => 29
```

Then I got error like this on my firebug:

```
postdata.split is not a function
toarr = postdata.split(",");
```

I think I have followed this method :
http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:methods

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing with the latest jqGrid and both jQuery 1.6.4 and 1.7.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like triley was able to solve it here:

http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/bugs/4-2-0-g-split-is-not-a-function-error/

I tried his fix and it works.

Comment: worked for me, very nice and easy fix. Just hope it doesn't regress once the next release is out.